# When is a Lightfoot Halfling obscured by another creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, halfling

> **Naturally Stealthy**: You can attempt to hide even when you are obscured only by a creature that is at least one size larger than you (PHB 28).

I haven’t been able to find a game definition for obscured (or concealed) in either the PHB or DMG.  The closest I’ve come is the rules for cover, which indicates a “target can benefit from cover only when an attack or other effect originates on the opposite side of the cover” (PHB 196).

How far away from a creature can a Halfling be and still be considered obscured by the “cover” provided by another creature?  Adjacent?  Within 10’, 30’, 100’? No limit?

Would the Halfling be obscured only from creatures on the direct opposite side of the obscuring creature?  Any creature on the generally opposite side?  Only when a line of sight traced between the Halfling and a creature passes through opposite sides of an obscuring creature’s space?

I can establish my own definitions for this ability, but I want to make sure there are no indications relating to this issue in the RAW before I do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Not being able find its definition in the game text means that "obscured" isn't a technical game term, it's just an English word being used, with its standard meaning, as part of the ability's description.

Is the halfling obscured by another creature? Is the obscuring creature one size larger than the halfling? Then the ability can be used.

Comment: Vision and light PHB 183 gives examples of lightly obscured so you'd have to translate those into gameplay